# Wildfly 29 Single Sign On only working for localhost not IP address

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly, undertow, elytron

I am trying to provide single sign on for a group of applications in wildfly 29, and so far it is working when accessing the application in a browser using http://localhost:8080/someapp; it shows a login form, i provide the right credentials and get access to the app

But if i try to do it using http://[my-ip]:8080/someapp then it does not work; the login form is showed, i provide credentials and i get redirected to the same form, no access to the app is granted

I am assuming that i has something to do with the undertow configuration, right now i have something like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:14.0" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-server="default-server" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}" default-security-domain="other">
.....
   <server name="default-server">
     <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
     <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
     <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
     </host>
  </server>
.......
<application-security-domains>
  <application-security-domain name="other" http-authentication-factory="myapps-security-http">
  <single-sign-on key-alias="localhost" key-store="myapps-keystore" domain="localhost">
    <credential-reference clear-text="secret"/>
  </single-sign-on>
 </application-security-domain>
</application-security-domains>
.......
</subsystem>
```

There are other parts involved in the configuration file but i think that is the most relevant to the problem.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If i change this line <single-sign-on key-alias="localhost" key-store="my-keystore" domain="[my-ip]">, then i can access http://[my-ip]:8080/someapp and everything works, but it does not work for http://localhost:8080/someapp. So what i guessed is true, but i don't know what is the correct value for that property. If i set 0.0.0.0 or *, it does not work